# Swift Signal SIGABRT error while making countdown timer?

Tags: swift, timer, sigabrt

I am working on a countdown timer for my app that starts counting down from 15. This is my code:

```
//


import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
     @IBOutlet weak var Timer: UILabel!


    var countd = 15








//
//
    override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    let time = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self,  selector: "updateCounter", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     Timer.text = String(countd)
NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(time, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    }

  func updateCounter(timer: NSTimer) {


        Timer.text = String(countd)

        if (countd > 0){

            Timer.text = String(countd--)
            Timer.text = String(countd)
        }

    }





        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

However, when I run it, as soon as I get to the part with the timer I see the label flash 15 for a second but then it immediately crashes with the SIGABRT error. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
selector: "updateCounter"
```

to

```
selector: "updateCounter:"
```

Please note that in Swift 2.2 it will become difficult to make this mistake (the compiler will warn), and in Swift 3 it will become impossible (string literal selector syntax will become illegal). You might want to update to Swift 2.2 *now* if you don't understand string literal selector syntax.